# Focus DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus, datatemplate

The behaviour I am looking for is that a selection of a Item in a ListView results in focusing the first focusable visualchild.

Problem: datatemplated data in a ItemsControler which does not get an initial focus.
In the example below there are 4 Strings which are then stuffed into a TextBox via Datatemplate.

Example:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <ListView>
         <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}" >
               <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.Resources>
         <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
               <sys:String>test</sys:String>
               <sys:String>test</sys:String>
               <sys:String>test</sys:String>
               <sys:String>test</sys:String>
            </x:Array>
         </ListView.ItemsSource>
      </ListView>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

I already tried some combinations of

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=[...]}"
```

pointless to say: without success.
Anyone a clou how I could get what I want without traversing the visual tree in c#?
It should be possible to do this, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

The FocusManager works sweet for this.

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" DataType="ListBoxItem">
            <Grid>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tbText}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Completed}" Margin="5" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteButtonTemplate}" Margin="5" Click="btnDeleteItem_Click" />
                    <TextBox Name="tbText" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                             Width="200" 
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                             AcceptsReturn="True" 
                             Margin="5" 
                             Focusable="True"/>
                    <DatePicker Text="{Binding Path=Date}" Margin="5"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the binding syntax in C# will not work, because that is how bindings are described in XAML. It might work to create a new instance of `System.Windows.Data.Binding`, and set its properties to the equivalent of what you would set in XAML, but I'm not sure what `ElementName` that you would be able to bind to in order to get this working correctly.

The only other option that I can think of is to add a handler for the `SelectionChanged` event, and set the focus manually, but that doesn't sound like the solution that you want.

Upon further inspection, I don't think that a Binding solution is possible. `FocusManager.FocusedElement` is an `IInputElement`, which doesn't have any members related to binding. I think that you need to traverse the visual tree in order to find the first object that is focusable. Something like this should work:

```
// Event handler for the ListBox.SelectionChanged event
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
    ItemContainerGenerator = generator.listBox.ItemContainerGenerator;
    ListBoxItem selectedItem =
        (ListBoxItem)generator.ContainerFromIndex(listBox.SelectedIndex);
    IInputElement firstFocusable = FindFirstFocusableElement(selectedItem);
    firstFocusable.Focus();
}

private IInputElement FindFirstFocusableElement(DependencyObject obj)
{
    IInputElement firstFocusable = null;

    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
    for(int i = 0; i < count && null == firstFocusable; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        IInputElement inputElement = child as IInputElement;
        if(null != inputElement && inputElement.Focusable)
        {
            firstFocusable = inputElement;
        }
        else
        {
            firstFocusable = FindFirstFocusableElement(child);
        }
    }

    return firstFocusable;
}
```

Comment: well even if I wanted to do it manually in c# I would need to get the reference to the textbox from the Datatemplate and with a little bad luck there will be more than one cascaded datatemplates inside so I would need to search for it...
It has to be possible to get the focus to the first input.

Comment: Strange that a thing as basic as this is not as elegant as the rest of WPF. I still hope to get an easy XAML based answer perhaps with .net 4.0. I hope you understand why I won't mark your post as the answer even though I will probably use a variation of that solution.

Comment: I understand. A few days ago I was playing around with a potential solution (FocusManager.FocusedElement is an attached property to most controls), but I still couldn't get anything to work.