# How can I force focus into the items of an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf

Here's a screenshot of my UI.
[image]

Everything's bound to a list of Question objects:

```
class Question
{
    public Answer[] Answers { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Answer
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

It's for an example I'm writing for a friend, and I'm still a relative MVVM newbie. (I know it's "not right" to have a UI concept like IsSelected on Answer, but it works without confusing the friend.)

Anyway, the left side's obviously a ListBox with the collection as its item source. The right side's a ContentPresenter with this snipped DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="question" DataType="{x:Type local:Question}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions> ...  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding Text}"
                                 GroupName="Answer"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I've got input bindings set up so PageUp and PageDown move through the questions. When the question is changed, I'd like one of the radio buttons on the right (preferably the selected one, if any at all) to be focused. The goal is for the user to use up/down arrow keys to select answers and PageUp/PageDown to move between questions.

I can tab into the radio buttons and the arrow keys work, but when I push Space to select an answer focus moves back to the listbox. Honestly I could do without the listbox getting focus at all. Setting Focusable to false seems to keep my focus inside the radio buttons, but even if I set IsTabStop to False the Tab key can still get focus inside the listbox.

In bad old WinForms, I'd have a SelectedIndexChanged handler for the list box that found the first radio button and focused it, along with GotFocus handlers to try and toss away focus like a hot potato. Since the radio buttons are part of a template, I don't see a clear or elegant path to do that. How can I get the behavior I want? "Redesign your UI" is an acceptable answer if it gets the job done, but I am hoping for a solution with minimal code-behind; it reminds me too much of WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to use `FocusManager` - see http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2008/06/setting-initial-focus-in-wpf.html and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/system.windows.input.focusmanager.aspx

Comment: I don't see how that will help. In order to use that technique, I need access to the element. I don't have that access because it's generated by a DataTemplate. What am I missing.

Comment: you could try to focus the Grid.Row

Comment: another way to do this using see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570194/focus-datatemplate-in-wpf/582843#582843

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you did not want to design the UI but you can make a ListBox look like a radio button list.  Not sure a WPF ListBox will do what you want but it takes and hold focus differently and you can set the SelectedIndex property.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do:

```
<RadioButton ...
             Loaded="RBAnswer_Loaded"/>
```

```cs
private void RBAnswer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    var answer = (Answer)rb.DataContext;
    if (answer.IsSelected) rb.Focus();
}
```

(To get rid of the code behind you could encapsulate that in a command using something like Blend Interactivity's `InvokeCommandAction`...)